# Checksum mismatch with linux 3.13.0-110.157 on launchpad

Tags: launchpad

I downloaded the source files for the package 'linux' from launchpad, and found that the size of one of the files is much larger than stated on the launchpad page. (The checksum also mismatches)

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/3.13.0-110.157

This is what I got when I downloaded the file (I tried multiple times, but it was the same):
3c7c8664e000c47fd27ce08cd7f869b5012d94ce8fffaf8a4100354914855912 *linux_3.13.0-110.157.diff.gz
Size: 39 MB.

This is what it is supposed to be:
linux_3.13.0-110.157.diff.gz    9.0 MiB f25359eae33f0d971e09d2ed6444767efacc60199ac559dc561cdd0d210cc73d

Could it be that this package has been infected in launchpad now with malware hiding in the diff?